# Not enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives, not able to install gparted

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I don't have enough space left in /var/cache/apt/archives, thus not able to install "gparted" so that I can increase Actual Size of Ubuntu vdi file. I have already increased the Virtual Size to 100 gig. But to make the Actual size to get increased as per Virtual size I need to perform partition on Ubuntu. Below are the details which can be helpful for you. Also let me know if there is any other way to perform the partition so that Actual size can be increased.

OS Inside my VM: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
VM Box: Version 5.2.8 r121009 (Qt5.6.2)
Host: Windows 10

Comment: @karel, I do not see any duplicates here in this path. Can you please let me know what exactly you mean by duplicates, in case I misunderstood rt you.

Comment: The other question shows how to shrink /var/cache/apt/archives which is the root of your problem.

Comment: ... or download a gparted ISO https://gparted.org/download.php and boot your VM from that ISO and change the VM's partitions with it.

Comment: One more thing, gparted is already present inside /usr/share/app-install/desktop but running gparted pkexec is giving me error that gparted is not installed.

Comment: @Karel, Nope, I have installed the Ubuntu from downloaded ISO image.